# CSS conditional variables

Tags: css, postcss

Currently I have many postcss files `item1.pcss`, `item2.pcss` etc each one styling specific components.

In some of them I need to do some custom changes to the CSS variables, as there is not always a 1-1 relationship between light and dark theme [alias tokens](https://spectrum.adobe.com/page/design-tokens/#Alias-tokens):

```
:root {
  --background: var(--palette-light-neutral-bg-default);
  --border: var(--palette-light-neutral-border-weak);
}

.dark-theme {
  --background: var(--palette-dark-neutral-bg-strong);
  --border: var(--palette-dark-neutral-border-strong);
}
```

If there any better way of doing this in CSS that I may be missing, instead of writing the `:root` and `.dark-theme`?

Comment: Check out this: [Using Custom Property “Stacks”...](https://css-tricks.com/using-custom-property-stacks-to-tame-the-cascade/) by *Miriam Suzanne*. It essentially explains using CSS *custom properties* to create an `if .. else-if .. else-if .. else` structure to assign a value to a regular CSS property by nesting `var(..)`.

Comment: Thanks @RenevanderLende will definitely read this